# Custom Query_builder function in Form Type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

from docs:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

How can I move query_builder function to external class and access query method from that class inside form type. My idea is to make code more modular, better so FormType does not connect to db on its own but using for example EntityRepository class for Entity

wanted code (abstract):

```
use Acme\HelloBundle\UserRepository;
// ...
'query_builder' = UserRepository->getSortedList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used Symfony 2.3 back in 2014, so you should use [choices](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/entity.html#reference-forms-entity-choices) then. Just include them or repository to form in options array , so form does not connect to db

1. include choices

```
    // in controller
    $object = ...;
    $form = $this->createForm(new SomeObjectType(), $object, array('user_choices' => $userRepository->getSortedList()));

    // in SomeOjectType
    $builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
        'choices' => $options['user_choices'],
    ));
    ...
    // in setDefaultOptions method
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            ...
            'user_choices' => array(),
        ));
    }
```

2. include repository

```
    // in contoller
    $object = ...;
    $form = $this->createForm(new SomeObjectType(), $object, array('repository' => $userRepository));


    // in SomeOjectType
    $builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
        'choices' => $options['repository']->getSortedList(),
    ));
    ...
    // in setDefaultOptions method
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            ...
            'repository' => null,
        ));
    }
```

I hope this will help to somebody with similar question